# Split multi-channel sound card into separate outputs/inputs on Macos

Tags: swift, macos, audio, core-audio

I have a sound card with 10 outputs and 4 inputs (outputs/inputs for the computer, it's a GoXlr if you know that device), and i want to split these channels into separate inputs and outputs devices for the system.

I successfully made the 5 outputs channels (outputs for the computer) by creating aggregate devices that redirects to the good channels each, but i didn't found any way to do the same for the inputs.

I need to do a device for the channels 1 and 2, and a device for the channels 3 and 4, but that seems impossible without creating a driver in c with non-documented api (and i don't think i can do that ahem).

I'm actually using Swift for my app but i can use another language if needed.

To summarise:

- I have a 4 channels sound card
- I want 2 devices, one for channels 1 and 2 of the sound card, the other for channels 3 and 4.

Anyone knows how can i do that ?

Comment: So you want to create a public aggregate device for other applications to use, which appears to have only two input channels?  I've done something similar (a multi-channel interface is presented as stereo pairs) _within_ an application, but that's just a matter of using a channel map.

Comment: Yes, infact if the device disappear when the app quits it doesn't matter, i want just to have an aggregate device with two inputs channels (like mics), and link it to two inputs channels of my usb device.

Comment: I'm not sure that would be possible with an aggregate device (though I don't know how you achieved it for the outputs either).  

 You might be able to create two aggregates and set the property `kAudioDevicePropertyPreferredChannelsForStereo` differently for each one to emulate the desired behavior in some cases.  Perhaps an Audio Server Plug-In could be used to advertise devices with the desired config and route the audio accordingly (but may be quite a bit more involved - I've never tried a plug-in myself)

Comment: That's how i did for audio outputs, but it's not possible to do the same for inputs, so that's why i wanted to look for an other way to achieve that than creating an Audio Server Plugin...

Comment: And no error when setting it either?  The docs certainly suggest that the property should work on ether input or output scopes.  Though it also depends on a client to check the property, which perhaps is not always the case here?

Comment: Absolutely not, infact i'm using [SimplyCoreAudio](https://github.com/rnine/SimplyCoreAudio) so mabe that's why i didn't found any way to set preferred channels for input and set custom channel map.... I'm going to look at the coreaudio documentation.